# Compiler error on using namespace's parameterized constructor of a class

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to initialize a class present in Typescript's namespace. This class has a parameterized constructor, but when I tried to use this class then compiler complains about it and I cannot use this class for instantiation.

```
**Inside file tv.dto.ts** 
export namespace tv{
           export class Trial{
             private name:string;
             Trial(name:string){
               this.name=name;
}}}
```

Inside my other Jest class file.

```
import { tv } from "./tv.dto";
import {Graph} from 'graphlib';

describe('testing',()=>{
    it('TestCase1',() =>{
    let k=new tv.Trial("WonderFulName");// It flags compiler error here.
    console.log(JSON.stringify(k));

    });
});
```

Error message which I received was "TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1."

Screenshot for the same.
[image: TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1]

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Edit:

I am able to resolve this issue by importing properly:
`import {tv as tv} as './tv.dto'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't export the namespace, instead just keep the export of `Trial`. Then import that instead from the same file reference.

Edit: Alternatively, change the constructor to use the word "constructor" instead of the class name.

Comment: I agree with you. It was a typo from my end. After creating new constructor and properly importing the namespace, I was able to resolve this issue.

`import {tv as tv} from "./tv.dto";`